# How can I get the last value of a field from a MongoDB table and display it in an Angular input?

Tags: angular, typescript, mongodb

I would like to know if someone could help me with my program.

What I want to do is a counter of a field, but the value I need to get comes from the last record of a data collection in MongoDB.

For example, I store a field called "consecutive" where I store the registration number. When making another record, I need my program to automatically be able to create that "consecutive" field and increment it by 1. However, to achieve this, I need to take the last value of said field from the database.

This way I get the data and store it in a variable called "data". However, I only want to get the information for the 'Consecutive' field, specifically the last value of that field.

folio.component.ts

```
data: any[] = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private apiService: ApiService){ 
    
  }

  ngOnInit(): void{
    this.llenarData();
  }

  llenarData() {
    this.apiService.getData().subscribe(data => {
      this.data = data;
      //console.log(this.data);
    })
  }
```

Comment: Just a note, where you state `However, to achieve this, I need to take the last value of said field from the database.` this is highly prone to issues in my opinion, for example if 2 users save data at the same time, you could theoretically get duplicate values. I'd look at mongos `counters` section here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/